# B+ Crash After Launch Pure Data (DAC issue)

Tags: raspbian, audio

i want to make pi as a portable recorder, mp3 player and portable DSP,
so i choose ES9023 DAC for B+ and 2B (there's an i2s input, that other hifi dac doesn't have).

[image]

i'm using raspbian and the kernel is 3.12.22+,
(i try a lot of kernel to drive the DAC, such as 3.12, 4.1, 3.18... but only 3.12 works)
after following the installing thread on the hifiberry website,
i type aplay -l it shows

---

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac], device 0: HifiBerry DAC HiFi pcm5102a-hifi-0 []

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

---

and aplay -L it shows

---

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ aplay -L

null

Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)

default:CARD=sndrpihifiberry

snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac,

Default Audio Device

sysdefault:CARD=sndrpihifiberry

snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac,

Default Audio Device

---

the result from command line seems fine, but when i use aplay to play a test wav file it shows

---

pi@raspberrypi /usr/share/sounds/alsa $ aplay Noise.wav

Playing WAVE 'Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono

aplay: set_params:1145: Unable to install hw params:

ACCESS: RW_INTERLEAVED

FORMAT: S16_LE

SUBFORMAT: STD

SAMPLE_BITS: 16

FRAME_BITS: 16

CHANNELS: 1

RATE: 48000

PERIOD_TIME: 125000

PERIOD_SIZE: 6000

PERIOD_BYTES: 12000

PERIODS: 4

BUFFER_TIME: 500000

BUFFER_SIZE: 24000

BUFFER_BYTES: 48000

TICK_TIME: 0

---

i try to use mplayer to play same wav file there's still no sound output from the dac board.
and when i trying to launch pd from the vncserver on my mac, it just crash and froze and shows

"disabling irq #32" from the b+'s 3.5mm video out

is there any advice or solution to fix this situation? or any recommend for the DAC?

Comment: `aplay: set_params:1145: Unable to install hw params:`Try `sudo aplay Noise.wav`

Comment: it shows: 
`Playing WAVE 'Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono `

 `aplay: set_params:1087: Channels count non available `

Comment: Next: try with a stereo sound, with and without `sudo`.

Comment: thanks, but just transfer into CCRMA's satellite and update the kernel into 4.1 follow the hifiberry's tutorial now i got audio output from my ES9023 dac and the source is pd's osc.